# SVG изображение меняет размер после применения transform rotate

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animation

Я сделал SVG с машиной (image), которая следует за мышью и держит ее переднюю часть к центру круга.

Это очень хорошо работает в Windows (проверено на Chrome, Firefox, Edge).

**Проблема**

Когда положение машины меняется и начинается вращение, машина меняет размер без причины. Это происходит (я думаю) на устройствах IOS (протестировано на Macbook - Safari и iPhone - Safari & Chrome).

Положение просто изменяется, устанавливая `x` и `y` изображения. Вращение (которое, я думаю, вызывает проблему) изменяется путем установки атрибута `transform`.

```
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', (xy.x - (12 * 0.25)));
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', (xy.y - (5.4 / 2)));
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + (180 - angle) + ',' + xy.x + ',' + xy.y + ') ');
```

Я сделал [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/065o4xke/3/), где при нажатии на кнопку происходит перемещение  машины на другую позицию . Пожалуйста, попробуйте это в Safari и Chrome, чтобы увидеть разницу.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57320784/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, сообщите мне, - если это то движение машины, которое вам необходимо:

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
var radius = 100 / (2 * Math.PI);
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var procent = 100 / (360 / 15);
var offset = 0 - procent / 2;

let angle = 0

function rotateCar(){
  requestAnimationFrame(rotateCar);
  angle +=.5;
  car.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', `rotate(${angle},21,21)`);
}

rotateCar()
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 42 42" width="100%" height="100%">
      <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="16" stroke="red" fill="none" />
      
      <image id="car" xlink:href="https://cdn.via.nl/img/mainmot/4.svg" x="2.1450689516760377" y="16.912873272286454" width="12" height="5.4" transform="rotate(0,21,21)"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```

В случае, если вы хотите центрировать автомобиль на дорожке, вы можете сделать что-то вроде этого: Вы оборачиваете изображение в группу. Внутри группы машина позиционируется так, чтобы она была в центре. Далее вы вращаете группу.

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
var radius = 100 / (2 * Math.PI);
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var procent = 100 / (360 / 15);
var offset = 0 - procent / 2;

let angle = 0

function rotateCar(){
  requestAnimationFrame(rotateCar);
  angle +=.5;
  car.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', `rotate(${angle},21,21)`);
}

rotateCar()
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 42 42" width="100%" height="100%">
      <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="16" stroke="red" fill="none" />
      <g id="car" transform="rotate(0,21,21)">
      <image xlink:href="https://cdn.via.nl/img/mainmot/4.svg" x="0" y="21" width="12" height="5.4" transform="translate(0,-2.7)" ></image>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Второй вариант движения машины**

Чтобы развернуть машину для движения вдоль трассы и для уменьшения её размеров применена команда трансформации:

```
transform:rotate(75deg) scale(0.75);
```

В svg для корректного вычисления центра вращения потребовались бы некоторые усилия. 
В css это реализуется проще:

```
transform-box: fill-box;  - контейнер по габаритным размерам объекта
```

И вычисляется центр вращения

```
transform-origin:50% 50%;
```

```html
<style>
.wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.img1 {
width:12;
height:5.4;
transform-origin:50% 50%;
transform-box: fill-box;
transform:rotate(75deg) scale(0.75);
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 42 42" width="100%" height="100%">
     
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#888888" />
      <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="16" stroke="#DEDEDE" fill="none"  stroke-dasharray="8 0.377" />
      <g id="car" transform="rotate(0,21,21)">
      <image class="img1" xlink:href="https://cdn.via.nl/img/mainmot/4.svg" x="0.5" y="21" width="10px" height="5.4px"  ></image>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<script>
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let angle = 0

function rotateCar(){
  requestAnimationFrame(rotateCar);
  angle -=0.2;
  car.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', `rotate(${angle},21,21)`);
}

rotateCar()
</script>
```

Comment: интересненько...